# Vim: Broken colors on start

Tags: vim, fonts, colors, xterm

I'm using uxterm and vim with the following .vimrc: https://github.com/dbrgn/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

When I open a file in vim and don't push any key, colored text is rendered using bold font and the [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) status line doesn't use any colors.

[image: Screenshot 1]

As soon as I push a key (e.g. by switching to insert mode, moving the cursor or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>), the syntax highlighting becomes correct and the Powerline colors show up.

[image]

This behavior isn't limited to Python files, it also happens with .txt files which don't use any syntax highlighting. Is this a bug or a misconfiguration in my .vimrc?

*Edit: I tried the same thing even with a .vimrc that only contained "syntax on", nothing else. Even then the syntax highlighting colors changed after pressing a key for the first time. This must be either a bug or a missing config variable.*

Comment: Try placing `set term=xterm-256color` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @Rain Great, that solves the problem! If you post this as a regular answer (preferrably with an explanation why the problem occurs) I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing

```
set term=xterm-256color
```

in your `~/.vimrc` file and see if it helps.

From my understanding the, problem occurs because when `Vim` first launches it reads the `$TERM` environment variable and displays the interface in a "safe" manner to insure that everything it sends to the terminal (all of the escape codes) is supported and all the text will be readable. When the user causes a screen update (by pressing a key, switching modes, ect), it asks the terminal what features it actually supports and then re-displays everything with all of the extra features enabled.

Setting `term` to `xterm-256color` forces `Vim` to assume that some of the more advanced escape codes (colored backgrounds, bold/italics, ect) are supported before querying the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently I can only award the bounty 24 hours after posting it. You'll get it tomorrow.